# SpriteKit Game slows down

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am writing an iOS app. It has a tab bar controller and one of the tab displays a view which has a collection view - it lists different mini games.
When I tap on the particular item, I show a view which consists of a both UIView and SKView. SKView presents the SKScene where most of the game play happens. There is a close button which closes this view and user is back to collection view.

Now everything works fine for first few iterations - Tap on a item in collection view, it shows a game and can play without hassle and close it. Animations are smooth. But if I just keep opening and closing this view, soon it becomes sluggish and animations are slower and slower. It also makes other parts of my app sluggish. I am clearing SKScene, deleting its children, also removing their actions. Instruments don't show any retail or memory leaks. Not sure whats going wrong. Please help!

Comment: Are you positive memory isn't increasing. Try profiling your App in instruments to see where the CPU is spending most of its time. Try removing code to isolate the problem.

Comment: Yes. Memory increases when m playing the game but as soon as I close the game view it is back to normal. Same with CPU usage.

Comment: Do you have your node count and draw count visible ? If so, are they what you expect ?

Comment: Yes, node count is proper. Basically I am drawing 9x9 grid of sprites and there are 81 nodes. When I close and open they are properly reset back to 81. But FPS drops and I am not sure why..FPS drops to 4-5..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question. **NEVER EVER** use **NSTimer** in SpriteKit. That was the problem in my case. Replacing it with update method fixed things for me.